# keyboard not show at first time(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

My code like this:

```
- (void)setupSubViews {
    [self addSubview:self.textView];
    [self addSubview:self.sendButton];

    [self.textView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(5);
        make.bottom.equalTo(-5);
        make.leading.equalTo(9);
    }];
    [self.sendButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self);
        make.trailing.equalTo(-9);
        make.leading.equalTo(self.textView.mas_trailing).offset(7);
        make.width.equalTo(60);
        make.height.equalTo(40);
    }];
}
```

The show function to make the textView becomeFirstResponder

```
- (void)show {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [keyWindow addSubview:self];
    [self mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.trailing.equalTo(0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(InputHeight);
    }];
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This view add to the keyWindow at the bottom of mainScreen, it's translate will changing follow the keyboard when the keyboard's frame changed.

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)noti {
    if (!self.textView.isFirstResponder) {
        return;
    }
    NSValue *endFrame = noti.userInfo[@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"];
    CGFloat endY = [endFrame CGRectValue].origin.y;
    BOOL isBackToBottom = endY == UI_SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    CGFloat needOffset = endY - (UI_SCREEN_HEIGHT + InputHeight);

    if (isBackToBottom) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, needOffset);
        }];
    }
}
```

Use Case:
viewController has a button, button click action like this:

```
- (void)beginChat {
    [self.inputView show];
}
```

self.inputView is the above customView,

```
- (LiveChatInputView *)inputView {
    if (!_inputView) {
        _inputView = [LiveChatInputView new];
        _inputView.sendBlock = ^(NSString *string) {
            ....
        };
    }
    return _inputView;
}
```

Now my question is that when we call `show` function at the first time after application launched, the keyboard will not show, but call `show` function in second time, every thing is fine.

How to deal with this question, THX.

Comment: for the first time when show function is called check that self.textView is nil or not.

Comment: are you testing from a device or simulator? on the sim its a common issue that the keyboard sometimes isnt working properly.

Comment: @Fahad Jamal I make sure self.textView isn't nil

Comment: @zero3nna test in iphone6s (10.2.1)

Comment: call `setupSubViews` in `viewDidLoad()` and `show()` in `viewDidAppear(..)`. Or, if this is not possible, show where you actually call it from.

Comment: @shallowThought `setupSubViews` is called in `init`, `show` is called in other button click action

Comment: have you tried calling `setupSubViews` in `show()` after adding the view (self) to your main window and before `[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];`?

Comment: @zero3nna I have tried, but it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake, call `[self removeFromSuperview]` in the function of `keyboardWillChangeFrame:`.

I thought `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` could only post it once at the keyboard show or hide, so i put the implementation of back action in `keyboardWillChangeFrame:`, and controlled by `endFrame.origin.y == UI_SCREEN_HEIGHT`

In practice, the fact is that:
when the keyboard show, `NSNotificationCenter` will post `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` three times:

**first**
[image]
**second**
[image]
**third**
[image]

**Tips:**
only first time show the keyboard after application launched, the first `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` of above three, the `endFrame.origin.y` is equal to `UI_SCREEN_HEIGHT`

**My solution:**
Observer the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, and do back action in this callback.

Thanks for all answers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this method is not a guarantee that the object will become the first responder.

As per **Apple**,

> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current
>   responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder)
>   and the new responder can become first responder.

Try calling *becomeFirstResponder* like below,

```
[self.textView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: THX, but it's not work for me. before the `[self.textView becomeFirstrespond]`, self.textView.canBecomeFirstResponder return yes